# Análise duplicada criando histórico de edição duplicado?

Tags: bug, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas, histórico-de-revisões

Não sei se isso pode ser conflito de edições, mas encontrei esta revisão:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/39950/revisions
>
> [image]

E sua análise correspondente:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21025
>
> [image]

O que pode ter acontecido?

Comment: Aliás, *outsourcing* é isso aí! Alguém de Petrópolis parece ter contratado alguém da India para fazer a NF I.m.p.e.r.i.a.l... lol

Comment: Eu vi isto e achei que era erro do usuário. Legal a observação do *outsourcing* :) E é isso mesmo. Nunca achei que ia ver isto. Aqui tem tanto programador que trabalha por prato de comida :)

Comment: Por um instante, achei que era algum *question banned* lá do SO aparecendo por aqui... Quem sabe um dia a gente não pode [trocar nossa rep por *food stamps*](http://www.programforfood.com/portals/3/codehtml.jpg)? :D . . . acabo de ver um comentário "odeio o governo" lá na pergunta, o pobre *contractor* vai ficar sem entender bulhufas ("wtf!?")...

Comment: Tem cara de bug mesmo. Reparou que consta que o ramaral aprovou a sugestão de edição duas vezes?

Comment: @bfav, acho que meu título duplicado/duplicado não ficou muito explicativo :)

Comment: Passei batido...